# Trying to install ruby on rails on windows for three days now

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

This is how it goes:

1) I go to rubyinstaller.org everything is good here

2) I download the installer and devkit everything is good here

3) I install both in that order then run command to link to devkit to ruby. everything is good here

4) I create a new app everything is good here

5) app is created and bundle install runs everything is good here

6) I start rails server this is where the problem starts

I get the message 'no such file to load' 'require' sqlite3 (LoadError) yadayadayada. I add '/sqlite3' to gemlick file and that is fixed. then I get a similar message for several files. e.g. nokogiri, loofah, rails-html-sanitizer and a few more.

After adding to name to the 'require attribute in each file all messages go away until I get the final error message that says 'no such file to load' rails/commands (LoadError) I have read numberous threads and tried numerous fixes but none work.

Any advice from anyone would do please. I am using windows 8.1 and was installing ruby 2.2.0

Comment: Add your Gemfile to your question.

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to install ruby on rails on windows for three days now

1. For the ultimate in simplicity, you can try the new version of the [rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#cha-beginning), where everything you need is installed in the cloud, so you don't have to install anything.
2. Or, the [old version of the rails tutorial](http://rails-4-0.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-rubygems) directs you to use [Engine Yard's rails installer](http://railsinstaller.org/en), which will install everything you need on your computer.
3. Or, you can try [installrails.com](http://installrails.com/)

Comment: @user3329978, Hold on.  I gave you the link to the old rails tutorial.  The newer version has a cloud setup, which means you don't have to install anything on your computer.  Reread my answer.

Comment: @user3329978, Any luck?